# Instantiate creates two objects instead of one

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am new at Unity, and i can't solve one issue for few days already. I created trigger object inside my road prefab that contains one more trigger and road itself. When car ontriggerenter with this object, i spawn new road prefab further z coordinate. I have one road prefab as starter, when my car hits the first road trigger event, it creates one object, when car hits trigger of the created prefab road, it creates two objects. So summary is, Instantiated objects triggers create two object instead of one.

I could make it through a backbone, but i want to know why it happens.

```
public class CreateNextRoad : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject Road;
    static float nextSpawnPoint = 149f;

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if(other.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            float parentPos = transform.parent.transform.position.z;

            Instantiate(Road, new Vector3(0f, 0f, nextSpawnPoint), Quaternion.Euler(0, 90, 0));

            nextSpawnPoint = parentPos + 109f;

            Debug.Log(nextSpawnPoint);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is because of OnTriggerEnter. It calculates two times. You can use this:

```
public GameObject Road;
static float nextSpawnPoint = 149f;
public bool touched;

private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if(other.CompareTag("Player")&&!touched)
    {
        float parentPos = transform.parent.transform.position.z;

        Instantiate(Road, new Vector3(0f, 0f, nextSpawnPoint), Quaternion.Euler(0, 90, 0));

        nextSpawnPoint = parentPos + 109f;

        Debug.Log(nextSpawnPoint);
        touched=true;
    }
}

private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
{
    if(other.CompareTag("Player")&&touched)
    {
        touched=false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, so this is native behavior of the method? I got it that it's been called twice, but why? Why static object execute once, and Instantiated twice?

Comment: Actually this does not work, it the same result, two objects created.

Comment: I don't know why this is happening but I had the same issue. And I fixed it like that. But I think it is becasue of unity can't be fast as enough.

Answer (score 0):

Ok.... 3 forums couldn't help me....

I found out how to make everything proper.
The idea is to call spawn next object method inside parent object from trigger child object.

Parent Obj script:

```
public class SpawnNextRoad : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject Road;
    static int roadCounter = 0;
    public void SpawnFurtherRoad()
    {
        float nextSpawnPoint = transform.position.z + 109f;
        Instantiate(Road, new Vector3(0f, -1f, nextSpawnPoint), Quaternion.Euler(0, 90, 0)).name = "Road" + roadCounter.ToString();
        roadCounter++;
    }
}
```

Trigger child script:

```
public class triggerSpawnRoad : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if(other.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            transform.parent.GetComponent<SpawnNextRoad>().SpawnFurtherRoad();
        }
    }
}
```

[parent obj](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kl3Kd.png)

[trigger child obj](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4if92.png)